# using ffmpeg to convert 60fps to 29.97fps without dropping frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have 60fps footage that I need to transcode to another format and also output as ~29.97fps.  I cannot drop any frame.

I have tried this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec dnxhd -acodec pcm_s16le -s 1920x1080 -r 30000/1001 -b:v 36M -pix_fmt yuv422p -vsync 0 -f mov output.mov
```

But it's outputting 60fps!  I tried without the `-r` and `-vsync` options and it produced 30fps, but the video was the same length as the input, meaning that frames were being dropped, which isn't acceptable.

For what it's worth, I see lots of message of the form:

> Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 282282, current: 282282; changing to 282283. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

How do I get ffmpeg to do what I want?

Comment: When you say "drop no frames" you mean including all the original frames, just slowed down to 29.97?

Comment: @SamForbis Yes.

Comment: The right question is not to "convert" but to "slow down", -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS", all frames kept, playback speed set to half

Answer (score 2):

FFmpeg's default behaviour, when changing frame rate, is to preserve source timing and duplicate/remove frames to match target frame rate. `-vsync 0` suppresses the frame duplication/drop but timing adjustment has to be done manually using setpts filter. Since you're increasing video duration, audio should be correspondingly modified as well.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "setpts=N/(30000/1001)/TB" -af "atempo=60/(30000/1001)" -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv422p -r 30000/1001 -c:v dnxhd -b:v 36M -c:a pcm_s16le out.mov
```

Comment: can you please suggest any way to trim video by multiple frame numbers and then concatenate it?